# Other resources beyond time and space in computational complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity, space-complexity

In general, in computational complexity, we talk about time and space complexity. That is, we think about how much time or space that is necessary for solving some problem.

I would like to know if there is another kind of resource (beyond time and space) that we could use a reference for discussing computacional complexity.

Comment: While I've not seen them discussed in the framework of complexity theory, other properties of a computation beyond space and time (latency) that one might seek to study are _throughput_ and _energy consumption_. The ability to produce partial results early might be interesting, so the latency to a critical first result might be studied in isolation from the latency to the full result.

Answer (score 3):

People have considered the number of references to external memory (https://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jsv/Papers/Vit.IO_book.pdf) and the use of cache memory (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache-oblivious_algorithm). Where the computations is split between two or more nodes, the complexity of communication between those nodes is of interest (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_complexity) and there are some neat proofs around here.

There are also links between these measures. Most obviously, using almost any resource takes time, so anything that takes no more than T units of time is likely to take no more than O(T) units of any other resource. There is a paper "An Overview of the Theory of Computational Complexity" by Hartmanis and Hopcroft, which puts computational complexity on a firm mathematical footing. This defines a very general notion of computational complexity measures and (Theorem 4) proves that (their summary) "a function which is "easy" to compute in one measure is "easy" to compute in other measures". However this result (like most of the rest of the paper) is in mathematically abstract terms which don't necessarily have any practical consequence in the real world. The connection between the two complexities used here is loose enough that it is entirely possible that polynomial complexity in one measure could be exponential complexity (or worse) in the other measure.